# Is it possible to "upgrade" the crafting materials?

Tags: diablo-iii

The crafting materials you get from disenchanting magic and rare equipment are tied to the difficulty level you're playing. Is it possible to convert the leftovers from the previous difficulty to the new ones? If so, how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[As of the 1.05 patch,](http://eu.battle.net//d3/en/blog/6268658) the Blacksmith can now upgrade crafting reagents as well as tomes at a rate of 10:1.  So 10 blue materials from Normal level will become 1 blue material from Nightmare level.  The option is available under the Craft Weapons tab, under a section called "Crafting Materials".

Comment: bwarner, how on earth did you do it? I read the patch notes and have been fooling around for almost an hour now trying to see where the upgrade resources tab is in the blacksmith interface and I just can't seem to find it

Comment: @Adrian Added the details of where it is.

Answer (score 8):

No, there is no way to convert crafting materials into the next level

The best items you can craft with a specific level of crafting materials will only break down into that same level of crafting material

However, you can sell them at the AH and buy the next level materials with the money :)

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way to upgrade existing materials but since buying mats on the AH is so easy, just buy what you need. (I usually buy stacks of 200 so i can get a few rolls) Its so cheap. 
I haven't broken down a single item since normal diff.